# Azure not applying migrations when I am publishing a Web API

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-web-app-service

I am creating a sample EF Core project using SQL Server and deploying it in Azure.

As of now, I have a `BookingAPI` service and there are 2 class libraries which are called `SharedServices` and `Domains`.

`BookingAPI` does **NOT** have an `ApplicationDBContext`. The `Domains` project has an `ApplicationDBContext` and all the domains are also, inside it.

`BookingAPI` is calling the `Domains` project to access the database.

The project structure looks like this

```
- BookingServices (Folder)
    - BookingAPI (ASP.NET Core Web API)
    - Program.cs
    - appsettings.json
        - appsettings.Development.json
        - appsettings.Production.json

- SharedServices (Folder)
    - SharedServices (class library)
    - Domains (class library)
        - Data (Folder)
            -ApplicationDBContext
        - Migrations (Folder)
            - Migration1
            - Migration2
        - Tables (Folder)
            - Bookings.cs
            - Tables.cs
```

As long as I was working in my local, it was completely fine. I could create migrations, and update the database.

But I want to deploy this project to Azure.

For that, I created a database in Azure and also published it from Visual Studio.

However, I am facing the following problems while publishing the `BookingAPI` to Azure:

1. If I add my connection strings in `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Production.json`, the Azure publisher can not find them. If I add them to `appsettings.json`, then they can be found.
2. Even if I referenced the `Domains` project properly (I am using `DbContext` for database update from `BookingAPI`), and there are migrations in the `Domains` project, these migrations are not found during publish and are not applied to the Azure database.

I am stuck here and can't find any context:

[image]

Now after waiting long enough I am getting this error in Publish page

[image]

Can anyone help me through this problem ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When working with different ENVIRONMENT, there are things you need to pay attention to when Publishing. Apparently appsettings.json is set by default because you didn't specify an environment when publishing.

If you have made all the environment settings, publishing for the Production environment will be enough.

> **dotnet publish -c ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT**

and an example for the production environment

> **dotnet publish -c Production**

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is solved now.
The main reason behind this problem was that my project was made in .net core 7 and the azure environment I was installing my service was .net core 8. I had to recreate the projects using .net core 8.